# Get some attributes of all the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code tries to get a list of all the checkboxes and the `_id` attribute along with a `value` to show if it is checked or not.
I am getting the `_id` OK but the `value` is always undefined. How can it fix it? Thanks

```js
let docs = [];
    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
      let doc = {};
      doc.id = $(this).attr('_id');
      doc.value = $(this).checked;
      docs.push(doc);
    });
    console.log(docs);
```

```html
<input id="someName" _id="idNeeded" type="checkbox"></input>
<label class="someClass" for="someName">My check</label>
```

Comment: `doc.value = $(this).prop("checked");` or just `doc.value = this.checked;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `checked` property of dom element in case of jQuery object it will be `undefined`

```
doc.value = this.checked;
```

for jQuery object use **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method

```
doc.value = $(this).prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) or [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) methods:

```
doc.value = $(this).is(':checked');
```

or

```
doc.value = $(this).prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checked property.

```
let docs = [];
    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
      let doc = {};
      doc.id = $(this).attr('_id');
      doc.value = $(this).prop("checked");
      docs.push(doc);
    });
    console.log(docs);
```